# LINQ, many-to-many request

Tags: linq

I have a table Users with ID field, have table

```
Services
   ID
   ServiceName
```

, have table

```
UserServices
  UserID
  ServiceID
```

classes:

```
User
Service
```

Class User has property-collection UserServices

i need to create LINQ request to get all users, which has at least one service, which has an user with `ID=5` for example.
How to make this LINQ? Thanks

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: did not understand your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you also have

```
User
   UserID
   Name
```

Then you can type something like this

```
from user in Users
where user.UserServices.Any(
   userService => userService.Service.Any(
       service => service.UserServices.Any(
           userService2 => userService2.UserID == 5)))
select user
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var usersOfService = from user in Users
                     where user.UserServices.Where(us => us.ID == 5).Count() > 0
                     select user;
```